# Where does the variables store in the SQL server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

for example if I declared one variable like - Declare @Test Int, where the SQL server store this variable?

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql) are not stored anywhere on the server. They are **session variables** that are omitted once the session is closed. You can only use a SQL variable in the same session you declared it, within the block in which it is declared.

Comment: Actually it's even stricter. You can only use a variable within the block in which it is declared, e.g. between the same sproc or even between the same `BEGIN` and `END` statements.